# How does application layer transfer the ip address to the network layer?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, hostname

lets say that i have an a web browser.
trying to connect to www.google.com.

the web browser send a DNS request on port 53 to the transport layer.
the transport layer encapsulate the request into a segment on TCP and transfer it to the network layer.

the network layer identified the packet and use the defulte DNS server ip address and send it to the Link Layer.

The Link Layer use ARP and etc..

getting the response.

the Link layer transfers to the network layer , and here is my question :).

does the network layer hold any table of hostname to ip?

from now on , the response should bubble up to the application layer.
dose the application layer add the ip that was extract from the dns request to the packet?

from what i understand the application layer should try to bind to a port , and then the transport layer should connect it some how via socket to the host name/ip or to report to the ip layer to do it.

but the question is how ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS response is simply a UDP packet containing a header followed by application-related data body. The data includes the domain name of the request, but this is for the benefit of the application that made the DNS request, not the network layer. The network layer does not analyse the content of the data body.

It's the application layer that decodes the DNS response packet and stores the IP address for subsequent use when it binds to a port; binding knows nothing about DNS names, it only knows IP.

Comment: ok , so how the application layer infrom the network layer which ip to use?

Comment: ok , can you specified?  what exactly happen there? i need it for a job interview.

Comment: Have you read RFCs [1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt), [793](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793) and/or any books on TCP/IP? It's kind of a big subject area and it's not very clear which part you don't understand. If for a job interview, I'd be reading like crazy.

Comment: yes i did , i was reading all of the tcpipguide.com
i didnt understand how the application layer said to the ip layer which ip to use in the packet while getting it from the network layer.

the answere is then you create a socket , you write your message to the socket , and there is where the network layer getting the ip and use it to create the packet.